Changes in JSON file are not reflecting
I am trying to create API and for client purpose i am using node postman.In delete method client is able to delete the json object but it is not reflecting in json file.
const express = require("express");
const user = require("./data.json");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();

app.route("/user/:id").delete((req,res)=>{
    const body = req.params.id;
    console.log(eval(body));
    user.map((obj)=>{
        if(obj.id==eval(body)){
            console.log("matched");
            console.log(user.indexOf(obj));
            delete user[user.indexOf(obj)];
            console.log("successfully removed=>"+obj);
        }
    })
})





JSON file data:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Lilah",
        "last_name": "Smitherham",
        "email": "lsmitherham0@odnoklassniki.ru",
        "gender": "Female",
        "title": "Accountant I"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Donaugh",
        "last_name": "Zanni",
        "email": "dzanni1@springer.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Quality Control Specialist"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "first_name": "Neila",
        "last_name": "Hillyatt",
        "email": "nhillyatt2@admin.ch",
        "gender": "Female",
        "title": "Registered Nurse"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Granny",
        "last_name": "Baszkiewicz",
        "email": "gbaszkiewicz3@tumblr.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Teacher"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "first_name": "Reinaldos",
        "last_name": "Christophe",
        "email": "rchristophe4@jalbum.net",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Recruiter"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "first_name": "Zebedee",
        "last_name": "Bulford",
        "email": "zbulford5@telegraph.co.uk",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Programmer Analyst II"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "first_name": "Maxie",
        "last_name": "Rudinger",
        "email": "mrudinger6@diigo.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "title": "Geologist I"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "first_name": "Vivi",
        "last_name": "Hiscocks",
        "email": "vhiscocks7@mozilla.org",
        "gender": "Female",
        "title": "Software Consultant"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "first_name": "Adlai",
        "last_name": "Charer",
        "email": "acharer8@foxnews.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Senior Cost Accountant"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "first_name": "Loydie",
        "last_name": "Stribling",
        "email": "lstribling9@mayoclinic.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "VP Product Management"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "first_name": "Farly",
        "last_name": "Champness",
        "email": "fchampnessa@unicef.org",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Operator"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "first_name": "Jasper",
        "last_name": "Dollimore",
        "email": "jdollimoreb@feedburner.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "title": "Media Manager IV"
    }
//so on 1000 users.
]

where is the mistake?

Please do not use the eval() function with untrusted user input. This code can allow an attacker to execute arbitrary JavaScript on your server. Replace eval(body) with Number(body) in both cases. Ideally, you should avoid the eval() function altogether.

Which of these is the JSON file? You don't save anything in the code. And this is delete user[user.indexOf(obj)] inside the map is generally a dubious operation. So is the method itself .map suggests that you are not working with a json object, but with an array

You've loaded a file into memory. Did you want to write that value back to disk?

Yes I want that if it is deleted by the request in postman it also get delete in json file.

there is some issues in your code need to be corrected

dont use app.route actully you can you app.delete("/user/:id", (req,res)=> {})

2.dont use eval beacuse its have security risks and attacker can run scripts in your code  Eval function
3.you using delete method in an array which just set that properties to undefind
4.you dont defined any case that return the response back to the user which may cuase the request hanging


const express = require("express");
const user = require("./data.json");
const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();


app.delete("/user/:id", (req, res) => {
  const body = req.params.id

  if (isNaN(body)) {
    throw new Error('invalid id parameter');
  }
  let newUsers = users.filter((user) => user.id !== id)
  // or you can use forEach method

  fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(newUsers), (error) => {                        
    //fs.unlink to delete 
    if (error) {
      return res.send(error)
    }
return res.send('successfull')
  })
})




isn't there way other than re-writing the file?

Since you've loaded your JSON data into an in-memory array, you can use various Array functions on it to search and modify it. When you're wanting to remove a specific item from it, you can use the Array.splice() function which you can read more about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
That function takes the element index that you want to remove, and then the number of elements that you want to remove from that position. In this case you just want to remove one.
You can find the index of that user by making use of the Array.findIndex() function. This takes a callback which matches against each record until you find the one you want and you return true. It then knows the index of the record and passes it back to you for you to use.
I would suggest using the following code for your DELETE endpoint:
app.route("/user/:id").delete((req, res) => {
    const userId = Number(req.params.id);
    console.log(userId);

    // handle case where user ID is not a number
    if(isNaN(userId)) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
        return;
    }

    const userIndex = user.findIndex(userRecord => userRecord.id === userId);

    // handle case where user does not exist - userIndex will be -1 if the ID was not matched
    if(userIndex < 0) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return;
    }

    // splice returns an array of deleted elements
    const deletedUsers = user.splice(userIndex, 1);
    console.log("successfully removed=>", deletedUsers);

    res.sendStatus(200);
});

I already mentioned this in the replies, but I removed the calls to eval() as it would pose a serious security risk in your application. Since a user can write an arbitrary string into that part of the URL, they could potentially pass arbitrary JavaScript code into your application which then gets run by the eval() function. This means an attacker could run their own code on your server, leading to it being compromised.
Since all you needed to do was convert the string to a number, you can make use of the Number() constructor function which is a handy way of doing this conversion. It also doesn't crash if the string you passed in wasn't a real number, and instead just gives you a special JavaScript value of NaN which stands for Not a Number. You can use the built-in function isNaN() to quickly check that before proceeding.
One more thing to keep in mind though is that this will only edit the list of users in memory, and it won't edit the JSON file. If you would like these changes to persist in your JSON file, you will have to write the JSON back out to the file each time you update or delete a user.
const fs = require("fs").promises;

async function writeUsersToFile() {
    const data = JSON.stringify(user);
    await fs.writeFile("./data.json", data);
}

You can then call the writeUsersToFile(); function from your DELETE endpoint and any other place where you modify the user list. In this case, you'd put this call underneath the call to user.splice().
    // . . .

    // splice returns an array of deleted elements
    const deletedUsers = user.splice(userIndex, 1);
    writeUsersToFile();
    console.log("successfully removed=>", deletedUsers);

    // . . .


thank you @crazy Redd for helping me out and giving me suggestion on eval, But somehow deleted user is still in json file.
let me learn more about API may be i found any solution. as i am a beginner in API right now it is possible i'll be making some mistake somewhere else.
Thank You

You get an ID to delete.
It is necessary to filter your current array by ID, excluding the passed ID from it and save it to a file
import fs from 'fs';
let user = require('./data.json');

app.route("/user/:id").delete((req,res)=>{
  const id = Number(req.params.id); // take id to number
  console.log(id);
  const len = user.length; // save len of array before
  user = user.filter(i => i.id !== id); // filter array
  if (len !== user.length) { // if length is different
    // save array to file
    fs.writeFile('./data.json', JSON.stringify(user), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('save to file');
      }
    });
  }
})

P.S.: There is no place to check this code, but it should work

I would avoid using Array.filter() here since it creates a whole new shallow copy of the user array. The larger that JSON file gets, the worse the memory usage will be. I think it's better to use Array.splice() here and mutate the array in-place.

@CrazyRedd It is doubtful, because first you need to run through the array and find the index of the element, then run through the array again, delete the desired element, and then you need to rebuild all the index numbers after deletion, and this is a rather expensive operation. For educational purposes, both will work about the same, but in real life it is closer to non-viable.

@Swad yes it did work but i would like to highlight few things
1)since user is const type i  had to change it to var.
2)we are re-writing the json file which i don't want to do.
I created a request where a new user can be added to json in that i rewrite the file (this is what was done in the youtube lecture i am learning from)
so is it that i have to re-write the file always??
thanks SwaD

@jainyashit If you do not overwrite the file, then the changes will only be in the process memory. node.js . After the restart, everything will return. The screenshots shown are not clear where the information is taken from, from memory or from a file. Your question sounded like "The data in the file does not change", so the answer is to change the file. Of course, you can overwrite the file once every N times or only at the end of the process, but it all depends on the goals
